Why does the density increment argument work?
I read Tao's post titled A Fourier-free proof of the Furstenberg-Sarkozy theorem. The theorem is:

Let $\delta > 0$, and suppose that $N$ is sufficiently large depending on $\delta$. Then every subset $A$ of $[N] := \{1, \ldots, N\}$ of density $|A|/N$ at least $\delta$ contains a pair $n, n+r^2$ for some natural numbers $n, r$ with $r \neq 0$.

The main step in the proof is a density increment argument, that goes as follows: let $P(\delta)$ denote the assertion that for $N$ large enough, all sets $A\subset [N]$ of density $\geq \delta$ contain a pair $\{n, n+r^2\}$ for $r \ne 0$. $P(\delta)$ is vacuously true if $\delta > 1$. It is shown that if $\delta_0 \in (0,1]$, then $P(\delta_0 + c\delta_0^3)$ implies $P(\delta_0)$. Furthermore, the authors claim that by considering the infimum of all $\delta > 0$ for which $P(\delta)$ holds, we have $P(\delta)$ for any $\delta > 0$. I want to spell out the details for this step.
Say $\Lambda := \inf\{\delta > 0: P(\delta) \text{ is true.}\}$. It is clear that if $\delta_1 < \delta_2$, then $P(\delta_1)$ implies $P(\delta_2)$. Therefore, if $\Lambda = 0$, then $P(\delta)$ holds for every $\delta > 0$. Suppose $\Lambda > 0$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then, $P(\delta)$ holds for some $\delta \in (\Lambda, \Lambda + \epsilon)$. Note that $f(x) = x + cx^3$ is an increasing function for $c > 0$. Solve for $\delta_0$ where $\delta_0 + c\delta_0^3 = \delta$. If $\delta_0 < \Lambda$, then we have a contradiction. If $\delta_0 \ge \Lambda$, then we probably need to repeat the process, but I'd be concerned about termination in finitely many steps.
How should I convince myself that $\Lambda = 0$? Thanks!

Try proving that $\delta_0\geq\Lambda$ is impossible for $\varepsilon$ small enough.

Suppose $\Lambda>0$. Choose $\delta_0>0$ such that $\delta_0 < \Lambda < \delta_0+c\delta_0^3$. (You can check this exists by letting $\delta_0=\Lambda-\epsilon$ and sending $\epsilon\to 0$.)
Now you have a contradiction, since $P(\delta_0+c\delta_0^3)$ by definition of $\Lambda$, so $P(\delta_0)$ is true, which contradicts the definition of $\Lambda$.
(Note that only one 'step' is required here.)
